# Calling a protected static Java method from Scala

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have a library here with some Java classes. One class has some `protected static` methods, which I realize is sorta an OOP no-no but I can't change its code. Assuming I have a Scala class that subclasses the aforementioned Java class, how can I call its protected static members?

Comment: Is it not an option to make a Java subclass that calls the super class method? You could then make your Java class accessible to Scala.

Comment: Ah, yes, I guess I could go that route. Thanks. Seems a bit odd that it's not possible directly though!

Comment: Maybe it's possible more directly in Scala, I don't know. That's why I posted this as a comment and not as an answer. Obviously, a "super" call cannot work because Scala has no static inheritance. Maybe you can make a Scala object that extends the class in question and then call "LibraryClassName.staticMethodName(...)", thereby avoiding to use "super"? I'm not sure if this would work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See **[Frequently Asked Questions - Java Interoperability](http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4)**:

> This is a known limitation of Scala:
>   there is no notion of 'static' members
>   in Scala.  Instead, Scala treats
>   static members of class Y as members
>   of the singleton object Y (the
>   companion object of class Y). When
>   inheriting from this class, one can
>   access only protected members of class
>   Y but cannot access protected members
>   of object Y.
>
> There's no way Scala can simulate
>   static protected without impairing the
>   integrity of Scala's object model in a
>   fundamental way, so this is not going
>   to change. To work around this
>   limitation, one has to create an
>   implementation of the enclosing class
>   with Java code which encapsulates all
>   accesses to the protected static inner
>   class.
>
> See [ticket #1806](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1806) for more
>   information and a concrete example of
>   the limitation and its **workaround**.

Comment: The "frequently" asked questions are so rarely asked that few people notice its existence. :-)

Comment: JFYI, this is fixed in 2.10.0-M2

Comment: @OlegYch: add that as an answer?